# book recommendation for mathematical logic - especially about formal system

Tags: logic, reference-request, book-recommendation, incompleteness

I just finished studying elementary first order logic through school course, and I am looking for some good books for studying more of mathematical logic.
I especially pursue to learn about formal system - (which was used for incompleteness theorem, and noted in a book by Douglas Richard Hofstadter.)

I am thinking of having book "A Profile of Mathematical Logic(written by Howard Delong)", but I'm not sure if this book is suitable for me.

Thanks for any advice for this.

Comment: See post [logic-and-metamath-book-recommendation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287607/logic-and-metamath-book-recommendation).

Comment: See post [recommendations-for-intermediate-level-logics-set-theory-books](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1460690/recommendations-for-intermediate-level-logics-set-theory-books)

Comment: See also R.Kaye, [The Mathematics of Logic: A Guide to Completeness Theorems and their Applications](https://books.google.it/books?id=EOjT_j-qOnsC&printsec=frontcover) (2007), wit supplementary [web material](http://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/R.W.Kaye/logic/).

Comment: Regarding incompleteness, see P.Smith, [An Introduction to Gödel's Theorems](https://books.google.it/books?id=sCkgAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (2nd ed, 2013).

Comment: Thanks for you comment. It is very helpful.

Comment: You are welcome :-)

Comment: Did you previously study deduction systems?

Comment: @shredalert yes, I also studied that through symbolic logic course

Comment: @강찬구 Mathematical Logic by Kleene might be worth looking into. You'll probably run into familiar things if you read the book but it goes into more advanced stuff near the end.